# CUDA | Cannot get high throughput using hostalloc

Tags: cuda, throughput

I'm currently learning CUDA, and I'm now focussing on the memory copy between host and device throughput. 
Here is a little program (see notes below) :

```
int NX=1000;
int NY=800;

int size=NX*NY;
size*=sizeof(PREC);
int threadsperbloc=512;
int blockspergrid=ceil(NX*NY/threadsperbloc);

//Allocate and instanciate host arrays
PREC *h_a;
PREC *h_b;
h_a=new PREC[NX*NY];
h_b=new PREC[NX*NY];
for (int i=0;i<NX*NY;i++){
    h_a[i]=i;
    h_b[i]=i;
}
//Allocate device arrays and a paged-locked host array to fetch results
PREC *d_a=NULL;
PREC *d_b=NULL;
PREC *d_c=NULL;
PREC *dh_c=NULL;
CUDA_CHECK(cudaMalloc(&d_a,size));
CUDA_CHECK(cudaMalloc(&d_b,size));
CUDA_CHECK(cudaMalloc(&d_c,size));
CUDA_CHECK(cudaMemcpy(d_a, h_a, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
CUDA_CHECK(cudaMemcpy(d_b, h_b, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
CUDA_CHECK(cudaHostAlloc(&dh_c,size,cudaHostAllocDefault));

//A little addition vector addition on the device
vecadd<<<blockspergrid,threadsperbloc>>>(d_a, d_b, d_c, NX*NY);

//Repeating copies from device to page-locked host memory
for(int t=0;t<30;t++){
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMemcpy(dh_c,d_c,size,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
}
cout<<"Check : "<<h_a[1000]<<" + "<< h_b[1000]<<" = "<<dh_c[1000]<<endl;
```

Notes : PREC is a macro (float in this case). Only one stream is used (the main one). I don't use the Async in this case, this is not the point. (I've tried but the throughput doesn't change).

With this little test, which I think is correct (and provides a correct numerical result), the Visual Profiler tells me that I only have a throughput of 1.52 GB/s (with an "attention" icon), each transfer being around 3MB (just for info). However using the NVIDIA bandWidthTest from the SDK it says

```
Device to Host Bandwidth, 1 Device(s)
 PINNED Memory Transfers
   Transfer Size (Bytes)    Bandwidth(MB/s)
   33554432         3177.5
```

I have a 3.0 compute capability and would like to achieve also the 3.smth GB/s of throughput. I've checked a bit the bandWidthTest.cu but I cannot see what I am doing different (they are using MemcpyAsync, but as I said, I also tried with no different result).
EDIT : Maybe you've seen that the test from the SDK is doing a transfer af about 33MB. In 10 times in fact. I've tried 30*3MB, 10*12MB, but no change.
So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I made a simple application out of the key bandwidth portion of your code, it is [here](http://pastebin.com/vk9SU2QU).  When I run that code, I get a reported bandwidth of about 6GB/s, which is correct for a PCIE Gen2 x16 link  (if bandwidthTest reports 3GB/s, I assume you are either on a Gen1 x16 link or a Gen2 x8 link).  When I run the same code in visual profiler (nvvp), in the "Detail Graphs" tab on the upper right, it reports max, average, and min throughputs of about 6GB/s also.  So it's not clear to me why you're seeing a difference.  Can you try running my code and see what it reports?

Comment: Thank you for your comment Robert. I compiled and ran your code (from terminal, using quasi no flag for compilation), it outputs bandwidth = 4569.385254 Mbytes/sec, pretty good! However, when I run the executable generated using your code in nvvp, I see also that it is limited to 1.54 GB/s and... wait! I recompiled, executed : 6 GB/s! Ran it again : 3! Ran it again : 1.1..Am I missing something? The device (stream 0) is supposed to be synchronized. I just don't get it

Comment: Something else is using the bandwidth.  Are you running a display off of this GPU?  Perhaps you should give a complete description of your system setup HW and SW.  Try running just a single copy loop (instead of 30, and you will need to change the multiplier in the bw calc) and see if you get more consistent results.  It's also possible that your system hardware power management is dynamically changing the PCIE link width and/or speed based on activity.  This can make it difficult to measure or get consistent results.

Comment: Yes I had the same conclusion. Using one copy (I doubled the dimensions) gives less bumpy results, around 3.1 GB/s. However, if I run it around once per second, sometimes (~1/10) it drops to 1.5 GB/s.  I ran again the bandWidthTest form SDK which says 5.4 GB/s. (Well, once more and it was 2.8, it's using a 10 iterations loop). What do you think can cause such fluctuations?

Comment: The two main things that come to mind are display activity and system power management.  But you haven't responded to my questions so I won't comment further.

Comment: You mean for the display? Does it mean an external monitor? But yes in fact it is on my personal computer, not a node cluster, so there is activity, but for me I cannot see how it accounts for this dynamic. I don't change window between execution, but maybe a process can indeed be using it. I shall try on the cluster next time. Thank you!

Comment: If you provide a complete HW/SW description (GPU, OS, cuda version, etc.) it may help.  If the system is a laptop computer, the computer may be doing an aggressive form of power management where it reduces the PCIE link speed or width.  This will cause apparent bandwidth to change by increments like 2x and 4x, which is roughly what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually other personal computer processes in place. I tried on a non-display GPU and it works fine.